# Оптимизация функций Js

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 функции: первая вставляет "-1" за 4 символа до конца строки, вторая их убирает. Код почти идентичный, можно ли его как-то улучшить?

```
function newStr(str){
    let length = str.length;
    let end = str.substr(-4, 4);
    let start = str.slice(0, length - 4);
    let newStr = start + "-1" + end
    return newStr;
}

function newStr1(str){
    let length = str.length;
    let end = str.substr(-4, 4);
    let start = str.slice(0, length - 6);
    let newStr = start + end
    return newStr;
}
```

Comment: Его можно улучшить, дав функциям и переменным адекватные имена.

Comment: Может посоветуешь какие?

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем, как что-то оптимизировать, следует подумать о целесообразности данного действия и к чему вы стремитесь. Я не вижу причин оптимизировать данный код. Можно в принципе сделать универсальный код, тогда это еще имеет смысл.

```js
String.prototype.insert = function (start, deleteCount, ...args) {
    return this.slice(0, start) + args.join("") + this.slice(start + deleteCount);
}

let first = "123456789";
let second = first.insert(first.length - 4, 0, "-1");
let third = second.insert(first.length - 4, 2);

console.log(first, second, third);

//Example
console.log("this is cruel world".insert(8, 5, "happy"))
```

Comment: А-ля `splice()` )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, с него и писалось) Только название изменил т.к. `splice( )` модифицирует исходную последовательность и будет не хорошо называть эту функцию так же.

Comment: Не стоит модифицировать prototype встроенных классов. Лучше определить отдельную функцию.

Comment: Спасибо. В данном случае целесообразности тут почти нет. Просто небольшой кусочек функционала в вёрстке..Но перфекционизм никогда не даёт покоя.)